# MergeSort functions failing in ANSI C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm a begginer in programming... I was asked in class to implement a MergeSort order algorithm and i am stuck with this, there must be some problem with the arrays management because the result is really weird, the first array has no repeated numbers, the result one do and they are not ordered. Help please.

```
int Merge(int* array,int ip,int medio,int iu){
int* arrayaux=NULL,i=0,j=0,k=0,n=0, OB=0;

if(ip<0 || iu<0 || medio<0 || ip>iu || medio>iu || medio < ip)
    return ERR;

if(ip==iu)
    return 1;

arrayaux=(int*)malloc((iu-ip+1)*sizeof(int));
if(arrayaux==NULL)
    return ERR;

i=ip;j=medio+1;k=0;
while(i<=medio && j<=iu){
    if(array[i]<array[j]){
        arrayaux[k]=array[i];
        i++;
    }
    else{
        arrayaux[k]=array[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;OB++;
}
if(i>medio){
    while(j<=iu){
        arrayaux[k]=array[j];
        j++;k++;OB++;
    }
}
else if(j>iu){
    while(i<=medio){
        arrayaux[k]=array[i];
        i++;k++;OB++;
    }
}

  for(j = 0; j < iu; j++) {
    printf("%d \t", array[j]);
  }
  printf("\n");

/*Copia el array auxiliar en el array original*/
for(n=ip;n<iu;n++){
    array[n]=arrayaux[n-ip];
}
free(arrayaux);
return OB;
}   


int MergeSort(int *array,int ip, int iu){

int medio, OBizq, OBder,OBc;
if(array==NULL || ip>iu)
    return ERR;
else if (ip==iu)
    return 1;
else{
    medio=(ip+iu)/2;
    OBizq=MergeSort(array,ip,medio);
    if(OBizq==ERR)
        return ERR;
    OBder=MergeSort(array,medio+1,iu);
    if(OBder==ERR)
        return ERR;
    OBc=Merge(array,ip,medio,iu);
    if(OBc==ERR)
        return ERR;
    return OBc+OBizq+OBder;
}
}
```

The functions must follow that definitions.

Comment: (1) Try to isolate the problem to the minimal compileable code that still shows the issue. (2) Please provide a test case + expected result + actual result. (3) Try to find where the problem is using a debugger

Comment: Your top priority now should be to learn some basic debugging techniques: you can do a lot with strategically placed `printf` statements, and you should also learn to use a proper debugger such as gdb or whatever your OS or IDE provides.